# PostgreSQL Diff of values of diff date from same table

Tags: postgresql

I have One table(daily_records) that contains many columns(d_date, d_amount, etc..). this table contains too many records, some records i show you below.

```
------------------------
d_date        | d_amount
------------------------
1-Jan-2011    |  100
2-Jan-2011    |  110
3-Jan-2011    |  115
4-Jan-2011    |  116
.
.
.
1-Jan-2012    |  220
2-Jan-2012    |  230
3-Jan-2012    |  225
.
.
.
```

I want to dates that difference between amount of current Records
 and amount of 1 year ago records and this difference should be in percentage and if this difference should be greater than 100% so this current Record's dates i want.

like example, The current Record is 1-Jan-2012 and his amount is 220.
and 1 year ago records is 1-Jan-2011 and his amount is 100.

```
int d1 = 220;
int d2 = 100;
double percentage = ((220-100)/100)*100 = 120;
```

percentage value is 120% that is more than 100% so This current record's date i want in result.

so How can i get this result in query?

Please guide me

Comment: You might want to try a self-join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query. It may not be the best way to do it but it works -

```
SELECT a.d_date as adate, a.d_amount as a_am, b.d_date as bdate, b.d_amount as b_am 
FROM daily_records a, daily_records b 
WHERE a.d_amount > b.d_amount
AND extract(month from a.d_date) = extract(month from b.d_date)
AND extract(day from a.d_date) = extract(day from b.d_date)
AND extract(year from a.d_date) - extract(year from b.d_date) = 1;
```